# Perform update and raise notice in Postgres Function

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to add a notice (or something similar) to a function that is executed on update by a trigger in PostgreSQL 9.6 db. I want to let the user who edited the table that something happened.
I don't know is "NOTICE" is the proper RAISE (Why not "INFO"?).

The central question is: **how I can add the raise notice argument after the update?**

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-SEVERITY-LEVELS), `INFO` is information implicitly requested by the user, which is not appropriate in this case. Please describe what you mean by "add the raise notice argument".

Comment: i thnik he wants to send to the user a mesage which updates the salary like here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f3c3159c8d376a4b55d7339875e12032

Comment: Yes nbk, that did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be, that level for messages is too high

so try this appproach

> ```
> CREATE TABLE id ( "id1" INT)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO id VALUES (1)
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> do
> $$
> declare
>   newnumer int = 90;
> begin
>    
>   UPDATE id SET id1 =  newnumer WHERE id1 = 1;
> SET client_min_messages TO INFO;
>   raise info   '"NOTICE" is the proper RAISE (Why not "INFO"?)' ;
>         -- catch notification
>       
> end;
> $$
> language plpgsql;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM id;
> ```
>
> ```
> | id1 |
> | --: |
> |  90 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f3c3159c8d376a4b55d7339875e12032)*